# How to write code to group ID with its code set in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

My goal is to collect data that contains "POSITIVE" result and code sets that must contain U071 or other codes that may be paired with U071 (as a code set). I was trying to group it by ID and CODE U071 only but realized it would only collect ID with U071 only (and not its other codes from each code set). I just need to group the ID with its code set and count it as 1 row. I know my code below is not correct, but what is the best way to group it by PTID with their code set? I hope my question is clear; if not, please feel free to comment below.

Table 1:

| ID | TEST_RESULT | DATE | CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | POSITIVE | 12-09-2020 | U071 |
| 1 | POSITIVE | 12-09-2020 | T34 |
| 2 | POSITIVE | 11-09-2020 | U071 |
| 3 | POSITIVE | 01-08-2020 | U071 |
| 3 | POSITIVE | 01-08-2020 | N99 |
| 4 | POSITIVE | 08-11-2020 | W39 |

Problem:
It will exclude ID 1 code {T34} and ID3 with {N99} as one separate set each, instead of recognizing it as ID 1 {T34, U071} and ID 3 {U071, N99} as 1 set each. In other words, ID 1 with code set {T34, U071} => need to count it as 1 row in table2.

Desired Goal for Table 2:

| ID | TEST_RESULT | DATE | CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | POSITIVE | 12-09-2020 | T34 |
| 2 | POSITIVE | 11-09-2020 | U071 |
| 3 | POSITIVE | 01-08-2020 | U071 |

Note: For ID 1, it does not matter whether CODE shows T34 or U071. The same applies for ID 3. I just need to group the ID with its code set and count it.

My code:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
SELECT ID, TEST_RESULT, DATE, CODE
FROM table1
WHERE TEST_RESULT='POSITIVE' AND CODE = '%U071%'
group by ID 
ORDER BY ID ASC;
```

Comment: If you want code to contain the string `'U071'` change to `AND CODE LIKE '%U071%'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select   ID
        ,TEST_RESULT  
        ,max(DATE) as 'Date'
        ,max(CODE) as  Code
        ,count(*)  as 'Count'
from 
         (
         select *
               ,count(case when CODE='U071' and TEST_RESULT = 'POSITIVE' then 1 end) over (partition by ID,TEST_RESULT) as cnt
         from   t 

         ) t
group by ID, TEST_RESULT
having   cnt > 0 and TEST_RESULT = 'POSITIVE'
```

| ID | TEST_RESULT | Date | Code | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | POSITIVE | 12-09-2020 | U071 | 2 |
| 2 | POSITIVE | 11-09-2020 | U071 | 1 |
| 3 | POSITIVE | 01-08-2020 | U071 | 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=2ac92dc08906f3575fe6aa3d6dd14b45)

Comment: I thought I put this comment, but I guess I did not: Thank you for the response! It did work! I want to ask if you can explain a little more about "then 1 end". I understand it is a case statement, but what does "1 end" mean? I appreciate it! @DannySlor

Comment: You're welcome! `end` is just a part of the syntax and is required in order to finish the `case statement`.  `Count` counts anything that's not `null` so if you change the '1' to '5' or '0' or 'dancing_chicken' it will still give you the same result.

Comment: I do have another question regarding your code you wrote. I am curious to know if there was a simpler way of writing the code, starting from the "From (select *,...)" all the way to the end. Could I rewrite to something like this? ``` FROM t     WHERE TEST_RESULT='POSITIVE'    group by ID, TEST_RESULT  HAVING cnt>0 AND Code IN ('U071')```

Comment: @kora_num14 with some dbms there's a thing called qualify that makes it simpler, but with most we have to do it in this manner. In Oracle you can do count distinct in a window function and that makes things simpler as well.